# Create mesh from cells and points in Paraview

Tags: python, csv, numpy, vtk, paraview

I have a CSV file with stress data and geometry that I have exported from ANSYS Mechanical that I would like to visualize in Paraview. Each node has a bunch of stress data related to it. I managed import the points as a point cloud in Paraview but I want to recreate the ANSYS mesh as well. I thought that "programable source" in Paraview could be an alternative way and with some googleing I could probably figure out how to read the data in to numpy arrays but the fundamental question is, how can I create mesh in programable source in Paraview from points and cells/faces?
My CSV file looks something like this:

```
Node, X, Y, Z, Stress_data
1, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 123
2, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 234
3, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 345
...

Faces
1, 2, 3
3, 4, 5
...
```

Update
[Here](https://github.com/Klabbedi/Paraview) is a link to an example csv file (connectivity column included), how the mesh looks in Ansys, how the mesh looks in Paraview and an slightly modified script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following python script creates a polydata object from your csv-file and writes it to a file, that can be read in paraview:

```
import vtk

f = open('Example-2.csv')

pd = vtk.vtkPolyData()
points = vtk.vtkPoints()
cells = vtk.vtkCellArray()
connectivity = vtk.vtkIntArray()
connectivity.SetName('Connectivity')
stress = vtk.vtkFloatArray()
stress.SetName('Stress')

line = f.readline()
for line in iter(lambda: f.readline(), ""):
    if 'Faces' in line:
        break
    v = line.split(',')
    points.InsertNextPoint(float(v[1]),
                           float(v[2]),
                           float(v[3]))
    stress.InsertNextTuple1(float(v[5]))
    connectivity.InsertNextTuple1(float(v[4]))

for line in iter(lambda: f.readline(), ""):
    v = line.split(',')
    cell = vtk.vtkTriangle()
    Ids = cell.GetPointIds()
    for kId in range(len(v)):
        Ids.SetId(kId,int(v[kId]))
    cells.InsertNextCell(cell)
f.close()

pd.SetPoints(points)
pd.SetPolys(cells)
pd.GetPointData().AddArray(stress)
pd.GetPointData().AddArray(connectivity)

writer = vtk.vtkXMLPolyDataWriter()
writer.SetFileName('Example-2.vtp')
writer.SetInputData(pd)

writer.Write()
```

Or you could use a programmable filter on your csv-file ([see here](https://www.paraview.org/Wiki/Python_calculator_and_programmable_filter)). This way I'm not sure how to feed node and face data into separate objects.

Comment: Thanks for your solution it almost solves my problem. I was able to generate the vtp file but the model looks strange in Paraview. Either there are some problems with my csv file or there is something I don't understand. In the csv array there is also a 'Connectivity" column that i thought wasn't necessary to create the model, could that be a part of the problem? I am happy to share an real example csv and also a cgns how i thought the mesh would look if you have the interest to continue to help me.

Comment: Maybe the model looks strange because the points of your face (1,2,3) are co-linear? Also, I was under the impression that the connectivity is given under "Faces". What other Connectivity information do you have?

Comment: I have now updated the question with links to some example files. Any ideas?

Comment: There were a couple of errors in my script, which I have corrected. Should work now. The nodal connectivity number I'm assuming is the number of tetrahedral elements that are connected to the node (see https://www.sharcnet.ca/Software/Ansys/16.2.3/en-us/help/tg_user/i1034630.html)