# How to avoid loops when building a vtkUnstructuredGrid with python?

Tags: python, vtk

I want to build a `vtkUnstructuredGrid` object using the vtk python module.

Every code snippets I found use methods like `InsertNextPoint()` and `InsertNextCell()` which require loops over points and cells like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45665130/create-mesh-from-cells-and-points-in-paraview).

There is an overlayer of the vtk python module called [tvtk](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/tvtk/README.html) which implements something intersting :

```
ug = tvtk.UnstructuredGrid(nodes)
ug.set_cells(cell_type, cells)
```

where `nodes` is a 2D numpy array containing nodes coordinates and `cells` is a 2D numpy array containing elements connectivity (in accordance with cell_type).
`tvtk` is much more *pythonic* than the `vtk` module but is unfortunately not as popular  and is more rarely available on clusters.

My question is : using the `vtk` python module, is there any way to set up a vtkUnstructuredGrid with numpy arrays like with tvtk thus avoiding expensive loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out [vtk_numpy](https://blog.kitware.com/improved-vtk-numpy-integration/).
E.g.:

```py
import vtk
from vtk.util.numpy_support import numpy_to_vtk, vtk_to_numpy

varr = numpy_to_vtk(myarray.ravel(order='F'), deep=True, array_type=vtk.VTK_FLOAT)
varr.SetName('myarray')
ugrid.GetPointData().SetScalars(varr)
```

Comment: Thank you. But how would you build cells and in particular how to define cells types ?